Pages/search returning limited results since mid-August
Using the graph API pages search to pull in locations, e.g.
pages/search?q=Scranton&fields=id,name,location,link
I used to be able to pull in results such as:

Rockville Centre, New York (108007899221124)
Lakeland Florida (334882786648235)

Now, only specific page-backed addresses are pulled in. I see this behavior in other meta connected apps I've tried, is there a change I am unaware of?
A search for Lakeland Florida used to pull in that location / ID as recently as a couple of weeks ago. Many other generic place names are missing.
